# Stretching the navbar item boxes to full width of browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am designing a responsive website using bootstrap. I am trying to make the contents (or) nav-item boxes to stretch to the full width of the browser.

I tried this by wrapping nav-items using container-fluid class, setting the width to 100%, still couldn't get the desired output

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link alert alert-success">Chicken</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link alert alert-danger">Beef</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link alert alert-warning">Sushi</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the output should be, all the colored boxes of nav-item to stretch to the full width of the browser, that is when the browser is squeezed to -xs size there will be a toggle button appearing on top right, when it is clicked there will be a drop down menu appearing, within colored boxes, those colored boxes should be stretched to full width of browser.

here is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ejzrmvxq/

Comment: I check the fiddle and, what appears to be the problem, is the margins/padding of the containers. Set them to, say, `0px` and see what you get.

Comment: @FDavidov i set the margin and padding of container to 0 px but still toggle button drop down  boxes are not stretching.

Comment: your .navbar class still use padding remove it and the boxes will stretch

Comment: It's because of the parent of the colored boxes `.navbar` having the `padding: .5rem 1rem;`.  Set `padding-left` and `padding-right` to 0

Comment: You may also wish to explore the possibility of adding the `!important` suffix to your styling section.